# How to trigger events in opencast v4.x

Tags: opencart, opencart-events

Can anyone please share a tutorial to capture the product add/update and product add to cart and cart update events implementation in OpenCart V4.
I was using that events by implementing them in install.xml, but I am not getting any clue how to implement them in v4.
Please help

Comment: The same like in OC3. Where you have a problem? Where your code?

Comment: I had code in install.xml that was trigger upon installation but not know how to update that code into install.json or write code in main controller of module.